# Usage of datasets when creating individuals or properties in Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl

I a using Apache Jena and create individuals and properties or data properties on these individuals.

In some cases I create the individual, then just after a property or data property on this individual. It happens that the individual does not exist when I try to create the property, leading to an exception.

I suspect that this comes from the fact that I am not using Dataset transactions.

I know how to create datasets from  my model, but how do I execute a model modification or read inside the dataset transaction if it is not a query?

For example I am doing things like:

```
OntClass c = m.createClass( NS + "SomeClass" );
Individual ind1 = c.createIndividual( NS + "ind1" );
```

Comment: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/txn/txn.html

Comment: Thanks, I am  now using your advice!